# Keeping punctuation in string while getting dictionary values

Tags: python

I have the below code and looking to get `abc, cde` as output. I have tried to convert the `None`s to empty strings using `str(i or ' ') for i in m` and got `abc cde` as output. Is it possible to isolate the comma `,` such that the output would be `abc, cde`?

```
d = {'1':'a', '2':'b', '3':'c', '4':'d', '5':'e'}
s = '123, 345'
m = [d.get(i) for i in s]
print(''.join(map(str, m)))

# output -> abcNoneNonecde
```

I managed to get the desired output by adding `',':','` to the dictionary, like below. But wondering if there's another way of achieving the same?

```
d = {'1':'a', '2':'b', '3':'c', '4':'d', '5':'e'}
d[','] = ','
s = '123, 345'
m = [d.get(i) for i in s]
output = [str(i or ' ') for i in m]
print(''.join(map(str, output)))

# output -> abc, cde
```

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to replace characters not in the dictionary with None to start with? `d.get(i, i)`?

Comment: Yes, I'm very new to python (started learning less than a month ago) and forgot that I could actually set i as default if i is not in the dictionary. Thanks for pointing out @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `i` as the default value for [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

```
d = {'1':'a', '2':'b', '3':'c', '4':'d', '5':'e'}
s = '123, 345'
m = [d.get(i, i) for i in s]
print(''.join(map(str, m)))
```

Or all in one line.

```
print(''.join(d.get(i, i) for i in s))
```

We can drop the mapping to `str` because all values are already a string.

Comment: `map(str, m)` is not necessary as `m` is list of strings.

Comment: Correct. I took the first code and made the minor change to `get`. Then I showed the shorter version without the unnecessary "conversion".

Answer (score 3):

Use the maketrans and translate functions

```
txt = "123, 345"

x = "12345"
y = "abcde"

mytable = txt.maketrans(x, y)

print(txt.translate(mytable))
```

This is the w3school link that explain the function:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_translate.asp